# Git-CodeCommit URL issues on OS X

Tags: git, macos, amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-codecommit

I am attempting to setup an AWS CodeCommit repository using my existing local project on my Mac. After creating the repository and setting up ssh I attempted to make the initial commit and got this

```
unix_listener: "/Users/<user>/.ssh/control:git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:22:<omitted username>.<something>" too long for Unix domain socket
```

I've also tried just `ssh git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` as is suggested in the AWS docs, but apparently this gets converted to the same thing, and thus gets the same error.

Anyone else run into this? What's the best way to resolve error or work around it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that your SSH client is trying to create a Unix domain socket to use for SSH's [ControlMaster](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5?query=ssh_config&sec=5) feature, but the path for the socket is too long.  The easiest way to fix this is to turn off ControlMaster for AWS CodeCommit connections.  For example, you can put this in your SSH config file (typically ~/.ssh/config):

```
host git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
    ControlMaster no
    User <username>
    IdentityFile <path to identity file>
```

AWS CodeCommit uses a separate connection for each push, so ControlMaster does not help the same way it does for other types of connections.

Comment: Thanks! FYI I also had to delete the ```ControlMaster auto``` I found at the beginning of my config.